# Bucle dentro de Bloque PL/SQL Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

Buen día, tengo un bloque con los siguientes elementos:

*TextBox
*CheckBox
*Label

en los TextBox ejecuto un query para que me muestre datos de una tabla, los checkbox me servirán para indicar cuales de los elemenos mostrados quiero ejecutar en un segundo proceso a través de un botón que no está en el mismo bloque, y por último labels para mostrar valores que no son de base de datos, este será un estado dependiendo del resultado de ejecutar unas funciones en el botón antes mencionado.

El botón lo que hace es mandar a llamar dos funciones dentro de un package en la base de datos, en el primero envío tres parámetros y me devuelve un valor de correlativo que utilizo para llamar a la segunda función, a esta segunda le paso como parámetros los valores de una columna que muestran los textbox, como pueden variar mi problema o inconveniente es el siguiente:

***Necesito recorrer cada uno de los elementos y verificar si están marcados sus respectivos checkbox, de ser así, mandar a llamar la segunda función por cada checkbox marcado y pasar este valor de primera columna (CODPROCESO) como parámetro, al finalizar el proceso, en los labels mostrar si se ejecutaron correctamente o no con algún mensaje.***

Imágen de muestra de la forma que trabajo:

[image: Bloque de Procesos]

Comment: Hola... mira por favor [ask] y tambien aprovecha y hace el [tour]. Esto es oracle forms? cual es el problema, porque no especificaste ninguno. Edita la pregunta con eso.

Comment: Listo @gbianchi muchas gracias por las correcciones, saludos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a ver si te sirve esto:

```
--Vamos al bloque que queremos recorrer y nos situamos en el primer registro
GO_BLOCK('nombre_de_tu_bloque');
FIRST_RECORD;  

WHILE :SYSTEM.LAST_RECORD = 'FALSE' LOOP
--Mientras no hayamos llegado al úlitimo registro

   IF :Nombre_De_Tu_Bloque.Nombre_CheckBox = 'S' THEN
      --Si el campo check está marcado ejecutamos la función
      ejecuta_funcion(con_parametro_que_sea);   
   END IF;

   --Nos movemos al siguiente registro
   NEXT_RECORD;
END LOOP;
```

Esta es una manera sencilla de recorrer un bloque de un formulario. La manera en la que funciona es muy similar a como lo haríamos de forma manual. Es decir, llendo al bloque que queremos recorrer, sitarnos en el primer registro y a partir de ahi vamos recorriendo todos los registro realizando las comprabaciones que deseemos.

Comment: Excelente ayuda, muchas gracias. Me ha servido un montón.