# ¿Cómo mostrar un resultado de tabla en Oracle Forms Builder Developer Release 6i en un lienzo diseñado?

Tags: sql, oracle, formularios

Estoy con Oracle Forms Builder, y a través de un lienzo diseñado quiero mostrar un resultado de una tabla PIPELINED.

Para ello, estoy codificando un disparador del estilo WHEN_NEW_BLOCK_INSTANCE en un bloque de datos. Y tener en Propiedades un Origen de Datos de Consulta del estilo:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(PAQUETE_RESULTADO.FUNCION_PIPE())
```

En el paquete, tengo un tipo de dato declarado en SPEC:

```
TYPE type_row_example IS RECORD(
      tipo_linea varchar2(1000),
      FECHA VARCHAR2(1000)
 );

  TYPE TABLE_ROW_EXAMPLE is table of type_row_example;
```

Y la función en BODY es como esto:

```
 FUNCTION FUNCION_PIPE RETURN TABLE_ROW_EXAMPLE PIPELINED IS
   v_type_row_ex   type_row_log_example;
 BEGIN
    v_type_row_ex.tipo_linea:='INFO';
    v_type_row_ex.FECHA:='2018-05-14';
    Pipe row (v_type_row_ex);
RETURN;
  END FUNCION_PIPE;
```

Los campos del lienzo son así:

[image: Campos de la tabla]

¿Cómo tengo que hacerlo en dicho programa?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, @Xtin9. He visto tu respuesta en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/152641/bucle-dentro-de-bloque-pl-sql-oracle-forms?rq=1, y veo que eres experto en ello. ¿Serías tan amable de ayudarme en mi pregunta, por favor? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Nunca he usado algo así y ahora mismo no tengo ordenador para podee echarle un vistazo. En un par de días estaré de nuevoo operativo y si no te han dicho nada te cuento. Lo siento

Comment: Hola de nuevo, @Xtin9. De acuerdo, toma tu tiempo. Si ves algo que pueda ser de gran ayuda, te lo acepto encantada. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

he estado mirando tu duda y creo que lo más sencillo para hacer lo que quieres es que crees una vista que haga la select a la función PIPELINED que has creado, de esta forma podrás trabajar con el bloque como si fuera una tabla normal y no tienes que realizar ningún tipo de precarga en ningún disparador ni nada parecido.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TBL_PIPELINE AS
SELECT * FROM TABLE(PAQUETE_RESULTADO.FUNCION_PIPE());
```

Comment: Hola @Xtin9. De acuerdo, lo tendré en cuenta para la aplicación. Muchas gracias.